# ExpressJS: response viciado?

Tags: node.js, express.js, ejs

Bom dia, prezados, estou com um projeto no ExpressJS em que a função é utilizar um painel de login para gerar um arquivo HTML com template EJS contendo os atributos do usuário que fez o login, ou seja, durante cada sessão de login um novo arquivo html com o nome do usuário será gerado e assim o Express redirecionará o usuário para sua respectiva página. O problema é que sempre que eu faço login com usuário diferentes em navegadores diferentes ele sempre retorna a página do primeiro usuário, mesmo que eu entre com as credenciais do outro user ele sempre vai retornar o primeiro user.

Este é o código do post

```
app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    const usuario = userAtendente.findOne({
        username: `${req.body.username}`,
        password: `${req.body.password}`
    }, function (err, obj) {
        if (obj == null || obj.isOnline == true) {
            res.send('err')
        }
        else {
            // usuario.updateOne({isOnline: true}).exec().then(result=>{console.log})
            console.log(
                `${obj.nome} acabou de fazer login no restaurante ${obj.restaurante}!`
            )

            ejs.renderFile(
                `./views/painel.ejs`, {
                nome: obj.nome,
            }, (err, html) => {
                fs.writeFile(
                    `./public/painel-${obj.username}.html`,
                    html,
                    err => {
                        res.sendFile(
                            `painel-${obj.username}.html`,
                            { root: `${__dirname}/public/` })
                    })

                console.log(obj.username)
                renderiza(obj.nome)
            })
        }Î
    })
})
```

Esta é a função que retorna a página

```
function renderiza(nome){
    app.get('/painel.html', function(req,res){ console.log(nome) })
}
```

OBS: Já verifiquei via console.log nos elementos obj.nome e eles retornam os nomes corretos dos usuários! Parece que só o Express está 'guardando' os dados do primeiro user e reutilizando nos demais logins. Agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar, toda sugestão será bem vinda!

Comment: `app.get('/painel.html', function(req,res){ console.log(nome) })` -> isso aqui não está guardando estado?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem seu código, mas acho que faltou algo como `app.get('/painel-${nome}.html'` nessa função `renderiza`.

Comment: Você me deu uma luz, amigo. Eu acabei removendo toda aquela estrutura do res.sendFile e a função renderiza(), substitui por um simples res.send(html), ao invés de criar arquivo e lotar o servidor de html é mais fácil enviar a página inteira para ser renderizada pelo client. Desde já agradeço muito pela sua atenção!